# how to avoid inferred type containing nothing with scala wart?

Tags: scala, scala-wartremover

using scala [wart](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover) I get:

```
  def lastWithRecursion(input: Seq[Int]): Try[Int] = input match {
      case head :: Nil => Success(head)
      case _ :: tail => lastWithRecursion(tail)
      case _ => Failure(new NoSuchElementException("No such element")) // how to avoid inferred type containing nothing.
  }
```

how to avoid `inferred type containing nothing`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with added generic to `Failure`:

```
def lastWithRecursion(input: Seq[Int]): Try[Int] = input match {
    case head :: Nil => Success(head)
    case _ :: tail => lastWithRecursion(tail)
    case _ => Failure[Int](new NoSuchElementException("No such element")) // how to avoid inferred type containing nothing.
}
```